# xml to php table alternating row color

Tags: php, html, xml

Trying to display an html table from and xml from php, getting error when trying to alternate the row base on even and odd mostly for styling the table.

```
foreach($bookdata as $book) // loop through our books
{
$i = 0;
        if($i%2 == 0)
   {
      $class = 'even';
   }
   else
   {
      $class = 'odd';
   }

  { 


        echo <<<EOF
        <tbody>
     <tr class='$class'>
                <td>{$book->date} </td>

                <td><a href='http://www.website.com{$book->dataNo}.html'>{$book->Name}</td>
               <td><a href='http://www.website.com/-{$book->authorcodeNo}.html'>{$book->author}</td>


      </tr>
    }
       $i++;
    }


EOF;
}
 echo '</tbody>';
echo '</table>';
```

Any help most welcome

Comment: define your $i = 0; out of loop

Comment: Also, take a look at ternary operators to clean up your alternating rows... http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators

Answer (score 1):

```
$i = 0;
foreach($bookdata as $book) // loop through our books
{
...
...
//and at end of foreach
$i++;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are redeclaring $i inside of your for loop so it's never going to actually increase, just get reset to 0 every single time. Also, not sure what's up with some of your curly braces as there's not enough code to see it all as far as I can tell... start by moving your variable declaration outside the for loop though!

Answer (score 0):

You are reseting the `$i` to `0` on every loop.

Remove

```
$i = 0;
```

from your code. And I didn't notice this before but the EOF is misplaced. Here is a full working solution

```
foreach($bookdata as $book) // loop through our books
{
    if($i%2 == 0) { $class = 'even'; }
    else { $class = 'odd'; }
    echo <<<EOF
        <tbody>
            <tr class='$class'>
                <td>{$book->date} </td>
                <td><a href='http://www.website.com{$book->dataNo}.html'>{$book->Name}</td>
               <td><a href='http://www.website.com/-{$book->authorcodeNo}.html'>{$book->author}</td>
            </tr>
EOF;
       $i++;
}
```

Comment: removed si =0; and corrected this EOF;
}
$i++;
    }
 echo '</tbody>';
echo '</table>'; works

Comment: @bignow23, If my solution works. Please accept it as an answer. Its the icon with the `tick` on the left side of the answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

try put the `$i=0` out of `foreach` loop.